# Create New Android Virtual Device

Tags: android-emulator

I installed lastest Android version 4.2, and SDK Manager. Now I create a project and create new Android Virtual Device doesn't display drop down menu for target and CPU/ABI. I installed ARM EABI v7a System Image.

Answer (score 0):

Are you installed some android platforms?

Go to the `AVD manager -> Available Packages -> Android Repository` and download one or more.

Also make sure that your `SDK` path is set if you are using eclipse to start the manager.

Go to `Window -> Preferences -> Android` and set the path. If done correctly, you should get a list of possible targets.